# LinearGradient Will no Render on Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo, styles, linear-gradients

I have a rather deeply nested component with a  wrapper around the entire thing. I made sure its properly installed and imported from expo, so no errors and the component renders, just with no Linear Gradient above it. The code is as follows, NOTE that the colors are 'black' and 'white' for testing, but eventually 'white' will be changed with a transparent value

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, ImageBackground, Image } from 'react-native';
import { LandingStyles } from '../../Styles/LandingPageStyles';
import LandingPageContainer from './LandingComponents/LandingPageContainer';
import Title from './LandingComponents/Title';

import backgroundImage from '../../assets/loginBackground.png'
import {LinearGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient';



const LandingPage = ({ handleLoggedIn }) => {
    return (
        <LinearGradient colors={['black' ,'white']} start={{x: 0.5, y: 1 }} end={{x: 0.5, y: 0.7 }} style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={LandingStyles.container}>
                <ImageBackground style={LandingStyles.backdrop} source={backgroundImage} resizeMode="cover">
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.4) !important',}}>
                            <View style={LandingStyles.titleIcon}>
                                <Title />
                            </View>
                            <LandingPageContainer handleLoggedIn={handleLoggedIn} />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Whenever I run the app to test, there's just no difference. I can comment out the Gradient and nothing changes. I've tried having it wrap the component (as shown above) or just being placed in as a single component (`<LinearGradient />` instead of `<LinearGradient> </LinearGradient>`) but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: try this and modify it like you want ( from my working code )

```<LinearGradient
                    pointerEvents={"none"}
                    style={{height: 60, marginTop: -60, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
                    start={{x: 0, y: 1}}
                    end={{x: 0, y: 0}}
                    colors={['red', 'yellow']}/>
```
but you miss height even when u do flex its not a same like height

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!